# What is exact event(global.asax) to clear cache in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Im working on asp.net website.
In some pages I'm saving the datatable into chache as 
cache["dt"]=dt;
 and using whereever I want in that page by fetching from chache.
I'm thinking that whenever session close I want to clear session in session_end event of global.asax file.
as cache["dt"]=null;
What is the better location to close either application_end or session end.
If I close in session_end will it affect to another user?
Please provide me clear helpful info regarding this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are putting the datatable in `Cache`, meaning, that it's shared by all the users, then there's no right place/need to do this, since the only time when it actually needs to be removed is when the application ends and at that point all resources are freed; your application is no longer running.

Perhaps what you should/meant to do was to put the datatable in `Session`. If that is what you want, then you could remove it `OnSession_End` in `Global.asax` but know that `SessionEnd` is not guaranteed to fire. You can also do `Session.Abandon()` when the user logs out, which will clear all session objects.

Comment: I have to use session.abandon() method in session_end evnt only right?. if session-end wont fire then how it will abandon the session?

Comment: @Ram no, not on session_end, what would be the point?If the user has to log in to your website, then you'd do it when he clicks on the logout button. If you don't require authentication, then never, no need to call Session.Abandon since SessionEnd will clear everything that was stored in Session for that user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the concept between Application Data, Session Data, and Cache. These three of them all different things.

- Application Data/State stores the information available in application scope, i.e. all session/user can access these data.
- Session Data store info for the current session data. The duration of the session can be specified in the configuration files.
- Cache stores frequently used data. And this data may be costly to regenerate every time.

In your case, since you are using cache, I assume that this cache stores some frequently used data. Ideally, this cache should always be valid, as long as the information does not changes.
As such, my recommendations is to keep this cache value as long as possible.

Comment: What if I placed data into session?. session will be specific to every user so I think evnenthouhh one user close the session another wont get affect and I can clear session in session_end evnt I think. advise me

Comment: Yes, session state will not affect another session. And btw, if you use session state, you do not need to do anything. It will be cleared automatically by the end of the session.